# how to implement textfield inside tile flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

hi i need to design this page [image]

but i'm new in flutter so i'm face difficult to manage to do it

here is my try

```
Container (
      child: Column (
        children: <Widget> [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Text(
              "Source Account",

              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30,
                  color: Color(0xff8aa1ba)),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            child: Card(


              color: Color(0xff343b4b),

              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,

              elevation: 10,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(7),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(

                    title: Text("Main Account 123456",


                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),textAlign: TextAlign.left,),
                    subtitle: Text("  Available Balance \n 10.000.9 KWD" ,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),textAlign: TextAlign.right,),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ),

          
          ),

        ],
      ),
    )
```

so can any one help me to implement this or give me an idea of how to implement a textfield inside a list tile or  card

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-input

Answer (score 0):

Put a Row inside of your title. So replace the your code with something like this:

```
ListTile(
        title: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                // your TextField's Content
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Card(color: Colors.grey, child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 8), child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text("Loans", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,),),
            Column(children: [
              Icon(Icons.add),
              Text("Amount", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,),)
            ])
          ]
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black), 
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
            ),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            textAlign: TextAlign.end,
          ),
        )
      ]),
    ),)
```

[image: screenshot]